# Why is "the additional level of backslashes is not needed in the first field because backslashes have no special meaning in data"?

Tags: text-processing, awk

From The Awk Programming Language

> In a  matching expression, a quoted string like  `"^[0-9]+$"` can
>   normally be  used  interchangeably  with  a  regular  expression 
>   enclosed  in  slashes,  such  as `/^[0-9]+$/`.  There  is  one 
>   exception,  however.  If the  string  in  quotes  is  to  match  a 
>   literal  occurrence  of  a  regular  expression  metacharacter,  one 
>   extra  backslash is  needed to protect the protecting backslash
>   itself.  That is,
>
> ```
> $0  ~ /(\+|-)[0-9]+/
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> $0  ~ "(\\+|-)[0-9]+"
> ```
>
> are equivalent.
>
> This  behavior may seem  arcane,  but it arises  because one level  of
>   protecting  backslashes is  removed  when  a quoted string is  parsed
>   by awk.  If a  backslash  is  needed  in  front  of a  metacharacter 
>   to  turn off its  special  meaning  in  a  regular  expression,  then 
>   that  backslash  needs  a  preceding  backslash  to  protect  it  in 
>   a string.
>
> **If the  right  operand  of a  matching  operator  is  a  variable  or  field  variable, as in**
>
> ```
> X  ~ $1
> ```
>
> **then  the  additional  level  of backslashes  is  not  needed  in  the  first  field  because  backslashes have no special meaning in
>   data.**

What does the last sentence mean?

Why is "the additional level of backslashes is not needed in the first field because  backslashes have no special meaning in data"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is *data* as opposed to *constants*, in the sense that `"abc"` or `88` or `/a|b/` appearing in the awk program is a constant, but an awk variable contains data, or `$0` contains data read from the input.  Data is not parsed, but constants in the body of the awk program text are.

Say you want to match the input `x+y...z` where there are 1 or more `y`'s so you need a regexp, but need to escape the `+` else it will just mean 1 or more `x`'s. So you can use any of:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ a = "x\\+y+z"; print a }
     NR==1{ b = $0; print b; next }
     $0 ~ a            {print "match a " $0 }
     $0 ~ b            {print "match b " $0 }
     $0 ~ /x\+y+z/     {print "match 2 " $0 }
     $0 ~ "x\\+y+z"    {print "match 3 " $0 }
' <<\!
x\+y+z
x+yyyyz
!
```

The last four lines all print that they match the same thing, eg `x+yyyyz`.
The `print a` shows the variable `a`'s data value is `x\+y+z` after parsing of the constant, 
the `print b` shows the variable `b`'s data value read unparsed from the first line of input data is the same,
and the final regexp constant, and string constant are equivalent forms.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give examples of using variables and of using "constants", so as to see how they differ?

Comment: I added an example that may help.